How do you look into sdb1 and sdc1 to make sure data is mirrored in RAID1 using mdadm?
I've spent hours fighting mdadm to the point I had to reinstall linux and do more fighting, mostly because of write-protected issues on the drives somehow (I still don't explain it), and also apparently because the resulting mounted multi-drive is owned by root by default (took me a while). It looks like it works now, mdadm is resyncing, and I can write test files.
... But what if it's just smoke and mirrors (pun intended)? I know mdadm has been around for ages, but regardless of whether I don't trust it (which I don't - or at least I don't trust my use of it) or because I'm curious, how do I actually look into sdb1 and sdc1 without removing the drives from the computer? Apparently I can't mount them because Linux doesn't understand them now that mdadm has added a header.

You can run mdadm --action=check /dev/mdX, and follow its progress in e.g. watch head /sys/block/mdX/md/mismatch_cnt /proc/mdstat. This should show mismatch_cnt as 0 throughout the entire test. If there are any mismatches, then data / mirror / parity is not in sync. This is the testing method that mdadm itself offers…
You can also mdadm --fail either drive (or boot with either drive unplugged) and see if the RAID still works. In a way this is the real test, since RAID has to be able to handle a completely failed drive. If you're also booting off these drives, you'll also test your bootloader configuration along with it.
However, this method of testing will likely trigger a full re-sync for each attempt when you re-add the drive later.
For RAID 1, you can set either drive write-mostly which means data will be read from the other drive. This is a non-destructive test that either drive will provide the same data when reading.
For the manual approach, you can get the data offset with mdadm --examine and mount read-only using mount -o ro,loop,offset=X. However this should be done from a Live CD / when the filesystem is not in use.
You can also compare data with cmp /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 SKIP1 SKIP2 (or --ignore-initial=SKIP1:SKIP2) option (set SKIP1 SKIP2 to the mdadm offset in bytes). If you can't determine the exact offset you could also simply start 1 GiB $((1024*1024*1024)) bytes into the devices, since the data offset is usually smaller.
You can also use filefrag -v -e to find out where a specific file is allocated then use dd or hexdump with skip options to try read it from either drive (with the mdadm offset added).

That's a great answer, thanks. Many options to choose from. Note that I've set up my Linux on a separate (non-RAID) drive so I can definitely do all of them if needed. Which one would you recommend to be reassured (as in "back to basics") without putting the data or the drives at risk? Does --fail only trigger a resync and automatically recovers after the ~7 hours of resync?
